# Laravel Migration Issue Remove index.php from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, migration

I am just developed a laravel CRUD Application and migrated to live server.

Currently am accessing the site like **http://example.com/index.php/manage-forms/** and its working fine.

how can i remove the index.php from URL.?

i dont have .htaccess in root, am not familiar with .htaccess issues. can u please share me the .htaccess file for viewing my site like **http://example.com/manage-forms/**

Thanks

Comment: You need [this .htaccess file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) in your `public` folder

Comment: Laravel comes with it's preconfigured `.htaccess` file found in the `public` directory. Maybe you haven't copied that to your production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess file is included in the laravel project on its own but if still you missed it in the process of transferring files from local to server add the following code in your .htaccess file under public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```